# Scala - how to filter list with two chars

Tags: list, scala, filter

I have a char List is Scala where I want to remove all chars that are not parentheses. The problem is I only seem to be able to do this for one character, eg:

```
 var parens = chars.filter(_ == '(')
```

If I try this:

```
 var parens = chars.filter(_ == '(').filter(_ == ')')
```

..I get nothing since I am filtering it once, then a second time which removes everything. How can I filter a character List (not a string list) for multiple chars?

Comment: Is the problem with calling `filter(...).filter(...)` that you need to scan the list twice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need/want a functional solution then try this:

```
val givenList = List('(', '[', ']', '}', ')')
val acceptedChars = List('(', ')')

givenList filter acceptedChars.contains // or givenList.filter(acceptedChars.contains)
```

Now you can add whatever chars you like to the seconds list on which you wanna filter the given list without changing filter call. If you want to leave chars that are not in the `acceptedList` just change to `filterNot`. Another advantage of this aproach, is that you do not need to write big lambda functions combining all the chars on which you wanna filter like: `x => x == '(' || x == ')' || etc.`

**Update**

Like **senia** proposed in the comment you can also use shorter version with `Set` just change function  `acceptedChars.contains` with a `Set` of given chars:

```
givenList.filter(Set('(', ')'))
```

Comment: You could also use `filter(Set('(', ')'))` instead of `filter(List('(', ')').contains)`. It's shorter.

Comment: In addition: for large collections `filter(largeCollection.toSet)` (`~O(1)` for each filtered element) is more efficient than `filter(largeCollection.contains)` (`O(N)` for each filtered element).

Answer (score 6):

This will remove all characters that are not parentheses:

```
val parens = chars.filter(c=>c=='('||c==')')
```

The following is what I tested in scala console:

```
scala> val chars = List('a', 'b', '(', 'c', ')', ')')
chars: List[Char] = List(a, b, (, c, ), ))

scala> val parens = chars.filter(c=>c=='('||c==')')
parens: List[Char] = List((, ), ))
```

The reason that your code removes everything is that... the first filter (`chars.filter(_ == '(')`) removes all the characters that are not `(`, which means only `(` remains. Applying `filter(_ == ')')` to this result returns empty list.